# McAfee is blocking Counter Strike 1.6

Tags: anti-virus, blocking

Just bought a new laptop (windows 10 64 bit Home) came with a licensed McAfee 16.0. The problem is I can't play Counter strike 1.6 anymore as McAfee keep blocking the game's files whenever I open the game.

I'm pretty sure my installation file doesn't contain any viruses :

I did google but couldn't find a way to make McAfee to allow the whole program to run without being scanned.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The file on the forum contains a non-licensed version of Counter Strike, so that's illegal.

Actually, you should just buy the game from Steam, and be happy with it. It's about 10€.

Sometimes, cracks are declared as malware/unwanted, as you don't want to allow your employees to use them. Also it's possible theres a virus included, you never know.

Comment: thanks for the edit and the answer. So now I think I need to reword my post to "How to make McAfee to skip scanning a certain program", should I create a new question or should I edit this question?

Comment: Neither comments now my answer will fit. It's another question.